# Change video of video tag on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a video tag say

```
<div class="phone" align="center">
  <div class="phone-inner">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted id="phonevideo">
      <source src="vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the video when page scrolls and each time div changes like fueled.com. Say I have six divisions like

```
<div id="first></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="five"></div>
<div id="six"></div>
```

When div 2 comes into view the video should change and when div 3 or 4 comes into view video should change again to something else. Here is my code which needs to be modified according to it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var topDivHeight = $("#first").height();
  var DivTop = $("#sixth").position().top;
  var viewPortSize = $(window).height();

  var triggerAt = 450;
  var triggerHeight = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + triggerAt;
  var test1 = (topDivHeight - viewPortSize) + 650;


  var count = 0;
  var number = jQuery.grep(mainTops, function(n, i) {
    if (n < $(window).scrollTop())
    {
      count++;
    }
  });

   $('.nav ul li a').css("color", "#fff");
   $('.nav ul li a#nav'+count ).css("color", "#f60");
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= triggerHeight && $(window).scrollTop() < DivTop) {
    $('.phone').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn();
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= test1){
      $('#phonevideo').html('<source src="vid/2.mp4" type="video/mp4">'); // tried using this method but its not working here. Some other method needed here.
    }
  } else {
    $('.phone').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Comment: removed php tag.. no php needed for this.. sorry brother my mistake.. :)

Comment: @ShubhamJha   from where you get this:- `mainTops` variable values? i didn't see anywhere it is initialized in your jquery code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly replace the HTML as you do using function `.html()`, accordingly to the HTML [specification](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-source-element.html)

> Dynamically modifying a source element and its attribute when the
>   element is already inserted in a video or audio element will have no
>   effect.

But what you can try as suggested by the document is to change what is playing, just use the src attribute on the media element directly and use function `.load()`;

A working example below:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
    player = document.getElementById('phonevideo'),
    source = document.getElementById('src');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  player.pause();
  source.src = 'http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4'; // change video
  player.load(); // load it
});
```

```html
<div class="phone" align="center">
  <div class="phone-inner">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted id="phonevideo">
      <source id="src" src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn" type="button">Change Video!</button>
```

Using jQuery as on your example (not tested):

```
   var player = $('#phonevideo');
   player.find("source").attr("src", "http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4");
   player[0].load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#phonevideo').find("source").attr("src", "https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4");
$('#phonevideo').get(0).load();
```

You can change source attribute like `$('#phonevideo').find("source").attr("src","videosource")`

and after changing source you need to load video `$('#phonevideo').get(0).load()`

Answer (score 0):

I've optimized your code. I have added a class to your divs and used the data attribute. Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zvsLnfcy/).

```
<div class="phone" align="center">
  <div class="phone-inner">
    <video width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="" loop="" muted id="phonevideo">
      <source src="vid/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="first" class="view" data-vid-src="vid/1.mp4"></div>
<div id="two" class="view" data-vid-src="vid/2.mp4"></div>
<div id="three" class="view" data-vid-src="vid/3.mp4"></div>
<div id="four" class="view" data-vid-src="vid/4.mp4"></div>
<div id="five" class="view" data-vid-src="vid/5.mp4"></div>
<div id="six" class="view" data-vid-src="vid/6.mp4"></div>
```

To see some result I have added some css:

```
.phone {
  position: fixed;
  height: 200px;
  width: 120px;
  background: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.view {
  height: 500px;
}

#first {
  background: red;
}

#two {
  background: yellow;
}

#three {
  background: green;
}

#four {
  background: blue;
}

#five {
  background: pink;
}

#six {
  background: black;
}
```

And now the jQuery part.

```
function getCurrentElement(pos) {
  var len = $('.view').length;
  var i = 0;
  var old_pos;
  var ele_pos;
  var old_ele;
  var return_ele;
  $('.view').each(function(){
    i++;
    offset = $(this).offset();
    ele_pos = offset.top;
    if(pos == ele_pos) {
      return_ele = $(this);
      return;
    }
    else if(ele_pos > pos && old_pos < pos) {
      return_ele = old_ele;
      return;
    }
    else if(ele_pos < pos && i == len) {
      return_ele = $(this);
      return;
    }
    old_pos = ele_pos;
    old_ele = $(this);
  });
  return return_ele;
}
var old_ele = null;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var cur_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
  current_element = getCurrentElement(cur_pos);
  if(old_ele != null) {
    if(current_element.attr('id') != old_ele.attr('id')) {
      $('#phonevideo source').attr('src',current_element.attr('data-vid-src'))
    }
  }
  old_ele = current_element;
});
```

I hope this code will help you. :)